# Where does this data comparing the CMB with Eddington's 'temperature of space' come from?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, temperature, cosmic-microwave-background

Eddington estimated the temperature of space assuming that star light would be scattered by interstellar dust. He came pretty close to the temperature of the CMB.

http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/Eddington-T0.html

Can anyone tell me where the raw data used in the graphs in this article came from? Is there a published paper I could refer to with the same comparison?

Comment: What difference does it make? Like the article said, they have no relation to each other. It's a coincidence, and it is not thermal blackbody. If you really insist I'd suggest checking what he said in his 1926 book, sounds like he derived some or all there. At the same freq as the CMB the author of your reference says Eddington was off by a factor of 700 million.

Comment: Aye, but we can't just believe everything we read on the web can we?